# Cache Manifest with ASP.NET MVC Downloads Correctly, But Site Still Unavailable Offline

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, manifest

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC web page that I would like to have available offline. I created a Cache Manifest file and included it as follows:

```
<html lang="en" manifest="/cache.manifest" type="text/cache-manifest">
```

(I included the "type" attribute because of Paul Styles' answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727306/html5-offline-application-cache-error-event-manifest-fetch-failed-1).)

The page I'm trying to cache is managed by the OfflineController.cs controller. The cache.manifest file itself reads as:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# rev 5

NETWORK:
*

CACHE:
/offline
```

(I used this syntax for the paths because of ZippyV's answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5148148/404-error-when-caching-aspx-pages-with-html5-cache-manifest).)

When I change the revision number and reload the page, the console shows:

```
Document was loaded from Application Cache with manifest https://[...]
Application Cache Checking event
Application Cache Downloading event
Application Cache Progress event (0 of 8) [...]
[...]
Application Cache UpdateReady event
```

This seems to mean that the manifest file was loaded correctly. Furthermore, when I Inspect the page and view Resources > Application Cache > cache.manifest, all 8 files are shown to have been downloaded.

However, when I unplug my Ethernet cable and navigate to ~/offline, the site does not load. Any ideas why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Was this error ever fixed? I realize that this was asked quite a while ago.

**Update**:
Hopefully [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049862/appcache-manifest-error) helps anyone else who come across this, this sound like a similar issue.

Comment: Ah, no it was not. This was for an internship I did several years ago; I remember that we came up with some workaround, but I can't remember exactly was it was. But thanks for asking :P